# Rails repeats Webpacker packages if I go back one page (OwlCarousel, DataTables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I've got a Rails app that repeats packages if I go back to the page that's supposed to render them.
For instance, my OwlCarousel with two images will multiply and have the carousel navigation superimposed on top of the previous one.

[Brief GIF to explain](https://i.postimg.cc/L8ppn8b3/Screencast-from-01-04-21-15-35-20.gif)

```html
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CRISPR Citrus</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    
   
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>


</html>
```

```js
#app/javascript/packs/application.js
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

require("jquery");

import '@popperjs/core'

//Owl Carousel
import "../js/owlcarousel"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

```js
#app/javascript/js/owlcarousel.js
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"      
      $( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        $(function () {
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
              {
                items: 1,
                loop: true,
                autoplay: true
              }
            );
          });
      })
```

```html
#owl carousel is simply called like this:
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-theme-dark">
        <%= image_tag "tmp/test_genotyping.png", alt:"", width:""%> 
        <%= image_tag "tmp/test_genotyping.png", alt:"", width:""%> 
      </div>
```

I think maybe OwlCarousel has a way to destroy itself before reloading, which I could add in `owlcarousel.js` but I think that would be a way to "patch" an ongoing issue. Is this supposed to happen?

Issue persits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone reads the post in the future, this was the solution I found.

Simply add:

```html
#in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<head>
...
    <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">
...
</head>
```

I couldn't make it work for specific view, so I simply did it for every view in the app. If anyone knows how to implement it directly within a view, I'm interested.